# ASP.NET MVC "Offline" Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I just got thrown onto an ASP.NET MVC project and was tasked with making an "Offline" page that shows up whenever a flag in the database is set to true. I check the value, and if it is true, I want the whole site to be offline for any request. I made an ActionFilter to the end and add it to all requests. Then, when a page is requested, I filter accordingly. However, this also filters the Offline page itself, so I made a line that checks to see if it is the Offline page - if so, it just returns. The problem is that the login page is forwarding like so: /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FOffline, which ends up showing the login page. How can I fix this problem?

```
public class DownForMaintenanceActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public DownForMaintenanceActionFilter()
        {
        }

        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // If they are actually visiting the Offline page already, abort.
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains("Offline"))
            {
                this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                return;
            }

            // We want to go to the "Down For Maintenance" Page if any of the following is true:
            bool siteIsUp = true;

            // Some other code here that sets siteIsUp = false

            if (!siteIsUp)
                RedirectToMaintenancePage(filterContext);
            else
                this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }


        private void RedirectToMaintenancePage(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                { 
                    { "controller", "Offline" }, 
                    { "action", "Index" } 
                });
        }
    }
```

How can I do what I want to do? Is this the best approach?
Also: How can I prevent a user from visiting this page when the site *isn't* down? Thanks!

Comment: is it not a better approuch to  make a batch file that adds or remove a app_offline.htm to the website

Comment: I have to make it automated for the client who knows nothing of such things.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is brittle because it doesn't play nice with routing. Routes can decouple controller/method names from the URL used to reach them, so if you get clever with routing down the road, this approach will fail.

I would apply the `DownForMaintenanceActionFilter` (btw, convention says that it should actually be named `DownForMaintenanceActionFilterAttribute`) universally, then create a second `Attribute` (something like `IgnoreDownForMaintenanceAttribute` with minimal implementation), tag your `Offline` controller/method with the attribute and ensure that the the `DownForMaintenanceActionFilter` checks for its existence and acts accordingly.

Take a look at the [`filterContext.ActionDescriptor` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor(v=vs.118).aspx). IIRC, most of the info you need will already be gathered for you.

> Provides information about an action method, such as its name, controller, parameters, attributes, and filters.

Unrelated: If I were creating a universally applied `ActionFilter`, I would be very careful about hitting up the DB on every request. Might be worth cacheing a value for a certain time so you connect to the DB less frequently.